# Add items to router but not links

Tags: routes

According to the last paragraph:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu/7

> Everything described so far is stored in the menu_router table. The
>   menu_links table holds the visible menu links. By default these are
>   derived from the same hook_menu definitions, however you are free to
>   add more with menu_link_save()

I need to do the reverse of that, which API do I use? I need to add a record to the routing table but not couple that to an visible menu link...

The only way I can think (short of manually INSERT'ing) is to initialize a *hook_menu* call somehow with the various paths I want and call menu_rebuild()??? This appears to be how Panels does it...

Suggestions, opinions, etc???

***EDIT | Why isn't this code working...resulting in "The requested page "/test" could not be found."***

```
function test() {
  return 'Do something';
}

function pagegrid_menu_hook() {
  $items = array();

  $items['test'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    'title' => 'TEST',

    'page callback' => 'test',
    'access arguments' => array('access content')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu links are only created by default because the default `type` for a router item is [`MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_NORMAL_ITEM/7):

> Menu type -- A "normal" menu item that's shown in menu and breadcrumbs.

What you need is a [`MENU_CALLBACK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7):

> Menu type -- A hidden, internal callback, typically used for API calls.

e.g.

```
$items['example/feed'] = array(
  'title' => 'Example RSS feed',
  'page callback' => 'example_feed',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

That will create you an accessible path with no menu links, unless of course you add them manually through code or the UI.

Comment: Excellent thank you...I literally just stumbled across that...for several years I have struggled with Drupal menus and suddenly they make sense :) thanks again...always a help

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: i'm getting a page cannot be found...any common reasons for this to occur? I literally copied some example code verbatim from various tutorials...making sure the $items keys were correct and still no luck...

Comment: Take a look at the name of your hook_menu implementation...it should be `MODULE_menu()`

Comment: Ugggh...sorry...such a petty error... :) Thank you very much...but again.